# how to hide the softkeyboard?

Tags: android

I've an activity that displays a view. The view consists of various widgets, one of which is a multiline EditText. When the view is inflated the softkeyboard comes up how can i disable it?

Things i have tried:

removing the following from the layout from within the EditText.

```
<requestFocus />
```

.

creating the following method then calling it from the oncreate method (resolution is the EditText).

```
private void hideSoftKeyboard() {

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(resolution.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your manifest file

```
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

as

```
<activity android:name=".youractivity"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide it by :

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

and when you need to show it use :

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
editText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
mgr.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

add this two lines at top view

ex:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" <-----
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" > <-----
    ....
    EditText
    .....
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When just u go on your apps manifest.xml then write for this code.

```
 <activity android:name="yourActName"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden" >
    </activity>
```